# How does the JVM represent an enum with one value vs multiple values? (Breaking Singleton rules?)

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums, singleton

Specifically, I am using a Singleton model using an enum. I have an enum singleton service (business logic) calling into an enum singleton dao. I would like to do write unit tests for my service but I can not mock my enum dao because, well, it's an enum and final. Yes, I saw the article about doing it with reflection, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

So my thought was this, why not add another value TEST_INSTANCE to my enum? (And that really is the core question.)

```
    public enum MyDao {
      INSTANCE,
      TEST_INSTANCE;

      public boolean methodIWouldMockIfICould()
      {
        if(this == TEST_INSTANCE) { return true; }
        ... //method code here
      }
    }
```

Trying this seems to work initially, but I'm hesitant.

1. This has a bad smell to me.
2. *Assuming* the code deployed to my web application uses only INSTANCE and that the only place TEST_INSTANCE is ever used is in tests, will this enum still follow the singleton model?
3. Is there anything else bad about this that I am not considering?

Thank you much in advance,
 -Matt

**Edit** I would love to use Spring for DI, but I am not allowed to. Legacy system and the higher ups have simply said "no, not yet." I have hopes that it will come, but I'm not allowed to yet, so this is my solution effort in the meantime.

Comment: Both INSTANCE and TEST_INSTANCE are singletons. If you want them to behave differently, just give them each different implementations of the method.

Comment: Thank you, EJP. At the risk of feeling foolish, which hopefully I can blame on a late night, I don't follow. I'm not aware of being able to have two identical method signatures in an enum where, if called on the instance of value 0 it uses one implementation and if called on the instance of value 1 it uses the other.

Comment: What is the purpose of an enum with only one value?

Comment: You shouldn't make your services and DAOs singletons in the first place. Why don't you use dependency injection?

Comment: @Patashu It is a design choice (much touted by Joshua Bloch) that can enforce the singleton pattern. See Item 3 in *Effective Java*.

Comment: Thank you JB. I ***entirely*** agree with using DI. I'd love to use Spring for it. I updated my original question to explain that unfortunately, my hands are tied. Addressing your other statements, why should they not be singletons? They are stateless and I see no purpose in utilizing resources to create multiple copies of the same object. What other model would be more appropriate in this case? (Tone can be hard in writing. Lest I be misunderstood, please know my questions here are sincere, not sarcastic or conceited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother to enforce the singleton pattern in your code using an Enum. Instead, just create a DAO interface and a corresponding concrete implementation.

In your unit tests, mock your DAO interface. In your production code, use dependency injection (DI) to stuff your concrete implementation into your other classes. Most DI frameworks will allow you to enforce the singleton property via configuration settings.

Comment: Thank you, Duncan. I ***entirely*** agree! I edited my initial question to explain that unfortunately, my hands are tied on that front. I'd love to use Spring, but I can't. :(

Comment: If your DAO is stateless, what do you gain by making it a singleton? Creating a new instance every time you need one wouldn't change anything: creating short-lived objects is extremely fast, especially compared to the time needed to execute SQL queries in the DAO. By making your DAO simple objects, you would be able to mock them in your unit tests, which you're not able to do by using an enum. Even if you keep this enum design, using an interface for your DAO would allow using a mock implementation of the interface in the tests, while still using the enum in the production code.

Comment: I didn't understand that creating a new instance every time was so cheap. Good to know. Using an interface for the enum sounds like an elegant and simple solution. I do like the enum style; it has a simplicity to it that I enjoy. Thank you so much for the ideas! I'll run with that!